# Copy file when destination exist and its open

Tags: command-prompt, robocopy

Im using robocopy from source to destination to update macro file (xlsm) in many folders. Point is that sometimes someone is using file from destination. Is there way to save file with different name when access to write is denied ? or maybe there is another easy to implement approach?